# getting a list of string placeholders using java stream

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have a string with a number of place holders, is there any way if we can collect all the place holders in one go with the help of java streams?

**Input:**

```
<Html>
 <Table>
  <TR><TD>||BuySell||</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>||ExchangeName||</TD></TR>
 </Table>
</Html>
```

**Output:**

```java
List<String> placeholders = [BuySell,ExchangeName]
```

Comment: Is the input in HTML, which you would first need to parse?

Comment: @Sweeper, Thanks for your reply. No it is a string. I have broken down the fixed html templates to different sub templates of Strings.

Comment: Have you? The input you showed here seems to me like a HTML string though, not a "different sub templates of Strings", whatever that means. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Sweepr, Thanks for your patience. What I meant is the input is a String.

Comment: Yes, I know the input is a String now, but is it HTML? If so, you should use an HTML parser. Are you using an HTML parser?

Comment: @Sweeper, we have tried using some parser, but was not successful. For time-being we are trying an alternate solution. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a helper function.

```
    BiFunction<Matcher, Function<Matcher, Object>, Collection<?>> placeHolderExtractor = (mch, extracter) -> {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(mch.find()) {
            list.add(extracter.apply(mch));
        }

        return list;
    };

    String htmlStr = "<Html> <Table>  <TR><TD>||BuySell||</TD></TR>  <TR><TD>||ExchangeName||</TD></TR> </Table></Html>";
    String regex = "(\\|\\|)([\\w]+)\\1";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher =  pattern.matcher(htmlStr);

    List<String> placeHolderList = placeHolderExtractor.apply(matcher, macher -> macher.group(2))
    .stream()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```